# Overwrite __init__ from a complex object

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to have a custom `complex` class that can get a string as input (`"1 2"`) and read the `real` and `imag` parts from there.

```
class myComplex(complex):
    def __init__(self, inp):
        real, imag = inp.split()
        self.real = float(real)
        self.imag = float(imag)


comp = myComplex("1 2")
print comp # (1+2j)
```

but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_complex.py", line 8, in <module>
    comp1 = myComplex(inp1)
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

does this mean that my `__init__` is not overwritting the one from `complex` or am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `complex` assigns the values of `real` and `imag` in [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

`__new__` is run prior to `__init__` and is responsible for the creation of the object. The execution (considering `myComplex` and `complex`) goes like this:

1. `myComplex("1 1")`
2. `myComplex.__new__(cls, inp)`
3. `complex.__new__(cls, real, imag)`
4. `myComplex.__init__(self, inp)`

(There is no `complex.__init__` since `myComplex.__init__` doesn't call it)

This means that the argument `"1 2"` is parsed before `__init__` is run.

You should be overriding `__new__`:

```
class myComplex(complex):
    def __new__(cls, inp):
        real, imag = inp.split()
        return super(myComplex, cls).__new__(cls, float(real), float(imag))
```